# CMD - separate windows

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, windows-terminal, windowing

With Windows 11 now using Terminal to show CMD, or Powershell, or Windows Subsytem for Linux, or what-have-you...
Is there a way to open a new CMD window, *in a new window*? Not just as a new tab in an existing Terminal window?

Comment: duplicate: [Open a new tab in the running instance of Windows Terminal from CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71689028/995714)

Comment: middle click the taskbar icon is the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Terminal will just respect your [`"windowingBehavior"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/startup#new-instance-behavior) setting. If you've got it set to `useAnyExisting` or `useExisting`, then starting `cmd.exe` should just open as a tab in the current window. Change that to `useNew` and it'll use a new window instead.